# Problems with zooming of my website on iPad

Tags: drupal, safari, zooming

I developed the following webpage: www.projekt-meine-zukunft.at
It is shown quite well in Safari, the problem is that two-finger zooming doesn't work. Now I have no idea why I can't make the webpage smaller with two-finger gesture like it works with other webpages. I would like to show you code-snippets, but I don't know which would help you.
Could it be a css-problem maybe?

The page is developed with Drupal by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following JavaScript code, which is presenting users from scaling by setting `minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1`:

```
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version"
                else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
                 browserName = "Safari";
                 document.writeln('<meta name="viewport" id="view" content="user-scalable=yes, width=device-width minimum-scale = 1, maximum-scale = 1" />');
                 document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="/themes/pmz/css/portrait.css" />');
                }
```

Comment: Aah, ok, thanks for your helpful response. One more question: Is it programatically possible to set the scaling?